# Change collision width and height of individual tiles in a tilemap

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, tile

I'm working on a game in Phaser 3, and need to be able to change the collision width and height of the wall tiles to something other than the width of the images, but I can't find anything that doesn't involve Tiled, which I can't use as it's a procedurally generated game.

I found a method to change the size of a tile, and I know how to get and individual tile, but nothing to change the collision size, and the few leads I found involved the differenced between the deprecated createDynamicLayer and createStaticLayer methods. The physics property of the tile object is empty, and doesn't contain the physics body of the tile, even though I set up collision between the wall tiles and the player (arcade physics). Any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Does the invisible physics object solution, work for your project, or do you need the tile physics body change? **btw.:** if you are planning on random generated maps you could check out [this example](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/tilemap/dungeon%20generator.js&v=3.55.2) on the official phaser homepage. It is a very interessting solution.

Comment: I think I can make the enemies collide with all of the walls, and it won't look unnatural with the pathfinding since there won't be anything on the other side of the walls, and have invisible physics objects that collide with the player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the greate application **"Tiled"**, the easiest option would be to set the tiles that should have a partial collision to not collide, and than iterate over the Map tiles and place invisible static physics bodies ontop.

It is maybe not very elegant, but it works well, and if you don't have > 1000 partial tiles on Screen, this should not be a performance issue.

**Here is a Demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536 /8,
    height: 42,
    zoom: 4.5,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity:{ y: 0 },
            debug: false
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create,
        update
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {

    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0x00ff00);
    graphics.fillRect(8, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(16, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(24, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.generateTexture('tiles', 8*4, 8);

    var level = [
      [1,1,1,1,1],
      [1,0,0,0,1],
      [1,0,3,0,1],
      [1,0,0,0,1],
      [1,1,1,1,1],
    ]

    // Map for the first level
    var map = this.make.tilemap({ data: level, tileWidth: 8, tileHeight: 8 });
    var tiles = map.addTilesetImage('tiles');
    var layer = map.createLayer(0, tiles, 0, 0);
    layer.setCollision(1);
    
    this.player = this.add.circle(16,16,4, 0xffffff)
      .setDepth(2);
    
    this.physics.add.existing(this.player);
    this.physics.add.collider(layer, this.player);
    
    let partialCollisions = [];
    
    map.forEachTile((tile) => {
      if(tile.index == 3){
        let partialCollition = this.add.circle(tile.pixelX + 4, tile.pixelY + 4, 1)
        this.physics.add.existing(partialCollition, true);
        partialCollisions.push(partialCollition)
      }
    });
    
    this.physics.add.collider(partialCollisions, this.player);
    
    this.keys = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

function update(){
  let speed = 20;
  
  this.player.body.setVelocity(0)
  if(this.keys.up.isDown){
    this.player.body.setVelocityY(-speed)
  }
  
  if(this.keys.down.isDown){
    this.player.body.setVelocityY(speed)
  }
  
  if(this.keys.left.isDown){
    this.player.body.setVelocityX(-speed)
  }
  
  if(this.keys.right.isDown){
    this.player.body.setVelocityX(speed)
  }
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```